# Why is Neo's body completely hairless until freed from the matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

Neo (and possibly everyone else) seems to be completely hairless (bald, no eyebrows etc) while trapped in The Matrix.

[image]
[image]

After being freed from the matrix, his hair starts growing normally.

[image]

What's up with the missing hair?

Comment: Seems likely that the goop the bodies were stored in had an agent that destroyed hair. Kind of like Nair.

Comment: @aryxus: It's Gelatin.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the slave bodies don't have enough energy for hair formation because the machines use people as batteries and absorb all their energy. So there was no energy needed for hair formation.

But after being freed from the matrix, his body starts to generate energy for his body and his hair starts growing normally.